# Visual Studio 2013 sql data reader

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm only starting out with this.  I've been over numerous tutorials but I just can't get this to work.  I'm trying to fill a text box with a result but it is not working.  I've even put in a `MsgBox("AA")` to check that the reader has rows and the msgbox appears but still it does not fill the textbox with the value.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class CustEnquiry
Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
        Dim connectionString As String = _
            "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;" _
            & "Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID;Password=PASSWORD"
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand( _
           "SELECT FIELD FROM dbo.TABLE WHERE VALUE = '092902D';", _
           connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("AA")
                TextBox2.Text = reader.GetString(0)
            End If
            reader.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

reader.Read()

i know that is short but that is the answer

Comment: Thank you, how did I miss that!  Will accept as correct answer in few mins.

Answer (score 0):

You have to advance the reader to the next(first) record, therefore use [`Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
If reader.HasRows Then
    reader.Read()
    MsgBox("AA")
    TextBox2.Text = reader.GetString(0)
End If
```

[`HasRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.100).aspx) just returns if there are records, it does not advance the reader. You could also use `Read` to check if there's at least one record in the result set.

```
If reader.Read() Then
    MsgBox("AA")
    TextBox2.Text = reader.GetString(0)
End If
```

Since you are selecting and expecting only a single value you could also use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the reader:

```
Dim field As Object = command.ExecuteScalar() ' is DbNull.Value if the field is null in the database '
```